# Determining the location of logfiles in Railo and ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, railo, logfiles

I'm looking for a way to determine the location of the log files that works in Railo and in ColdFusion. So far I found solutions for Railo and ColdFusion, but none that works in both.

[Solution for Railo](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/railo/lC4U7oZwToY)

[Solution for ColdFusion](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2009/2/11/Determining-the-location-of-ColdFusions-log-files)

One way would be to build a switch that calls the correct solution for Railo or ColdFusion depending on the server, but I'd rather have a single method that works in both.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am not sure there is one. What is the issue with your current solution? Seems clean enough to have a single function that returns the log location, and do the switch/case logic inside it based on the current environment. Not ideal, but we do not live ideal world ;-) Some things (usually internal stuff) will always vary a bit by engine.

Comment: There isn't a unified way of doing it: they're different systems, implemented different ways. Why do you need to know this location? I'm not suggesting you shouldn't, but knowing what you're doing might help us give some better/different suggestions.

Comment: We are creating a custom logfile that has a different structure than the 'official' logs, but should be placed in the same directory as the others, so, we can't use the writelog()-function. Since this custom logfile will be used on all our servers, no matter if Railo or CF, we need a solution for both. And no, there's nothing wrong with the switch solution, it would have just been a little bit more elegant to have a single solution ;)

Comment: To Adam's point, another option might be to add your customization via the configuration settings of each system's logging facility instead of writing code. For example. Adobe CF uses log4j for it's logging so you might be able to make your changes in the `log4J.properties` file. I think Railo uses sl4j but not sure.

Comment: You can use `server` variables to detect which system you are on. See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0c35c-7fdb.html for ACF

Answer (score 0):

Up to Railo 4.1 logging in Railo is done with proprietary code and you do not have much control over the logs.

In Railo 4.2 (soon to enter beta phase) logging will done with log4j and you will have much more control on what is logged and where via the admin UI.